# How to set a MKNetworkingKit request synchron?

Tags: networking, ios5, synchronous

I'm using MKNetworkingKit for the interaction with the webserver.
Is it possible, to set the request synchron?

Answer (score 0):

Bit late of an answer but seeing as there is none.

There is currently no support for synchronous loading, and the author said that he isn't planning on adding it anywhere soon.

Comment: Also a bit late. ;) But thanks for your answer. I'm using AFNetworking now.